# On unix file play

Tags: command-line

Lately i was working on command rm for removing useless file from my home directory.There was a file #abd# which could not be removed using simple rm command using either of the option -r or -f.I had to put that name in double inverted commas and then remove it.Hence could you tell me what does this # indicates and what does this file interpret to unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` denotes comments.

When you typed `rm -rf #abd#`, the system read it as `rm -rf` and threw an error.

By putting it in `"double ticks"`, you forced the system to recognize it as a string and not a comment. You can also "escape" the `#` by doing something like this: `rm -rf \#abd\#`.

To show this point more clearly, run some (safe) commands:

```
echo Hello #World
echo "Hello #World"
echo Hello_\#World
```

The first will return `Hello` while the second will return `Hello #World`. The third will return `Hello_#World`.

Programs might do hash-naming to make their files hard to delete. This is a good way to ensure that an important file for a program isn't removed, causinc crashes and other issues.

Comment: Or escape the # `touch \#file` and then `rm \#file` will work